# Different values dates in MYSQL 5 vs MYSQL 8

Tags: mysql, date, parsing

I am working with a `MYSQL 5` database, whose data model has a 'date' column defined. This column defaults to the value '0000-01-01'. Using `JPA`, when I receive the full entity, I receive this date-field with the value '0000-12-29'. However, changing the `MYSQL` version to a later one (`MYSQL 8`), I get the value '0000-12-30'.

Logs from `SLF4j` with each version of `MYSQL`

Version 5:

```
Date comparing: date received from database: 0000-12-29
```

Version 8:

```
Date comparing: date received from database: 0000-12-30
```

***What are these changes due to?***

***Should I control both dates in back-end?***
If we migrate to a higher version of `MYSQL`, we will hace problem with this types of dates.

Comment: Both values are incorrect. Searching for the reason why one incorrect value is changed with another one makes no sense. Fix your data instead.

Comment: @Akina I can not change anything in database because is a 'data-model' that we received from the data-team

Comment: I have the impression that your Java framework is using MySQL server's time zone to convert to local time zone, and both servers have different values. The robust fix here would probably be setting time zone at application level, rather than relying on defaults, so changes in server settings don't break your app.

Comment: Are these TIMESTAMP columns? Are you dealing with some goofy side-effect of the timezone processing that comes with TIMESTAMPs? Try issuing `SET time_zone = 'UTC';` before you do this work. Like @ÁlvaroGonzález said. And, this data is defective: those date values are not valid. Tell your data team to fix it.